# How to use variable in python __init__ inside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, queue

Consider the following code: i have a class named X. this class is initialised with some an initial value. In the class, I want to initiate queue data structure with the initvalues of the class. Since this queue will be used later in many other functions in the class and it needs to have elements. Here we cant use initvalues since an error is shown. How can I do this? thank you

```
class X :
def __init__(self, initvalues):
        self.initvalues=initvalues

queue= dequeu(initivalues)
```

Comment: If that's based on an instance attribute, shouldn't it *also* be an instance attribute?

Answer (score 0):

`initivalues` is an attribute of class `X`. In order to access this attribute, you have to call it through its class. Try to change `queue= dequeu(initivalues)` to `queue= dequeu(X.initivalues)`.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, `initvalues` is not a class attribute, it is an instance attribute of the class.  Put another way, it is only accessible through instances of class `X`, not through class `X` itself.

Example:

```
from collections import deque
class X:
    def __init__(self, initvalues):
        self.initvalues=initvalues

one_x = X([1, 2, 3])

queue= deque(one_x.initvalues)

print(queue)
```

Output:

```
deque([1, 2, 3])
```